# How can I see the signal strength and type of connection (2G/3G) using a usb modem in Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, modem, umts

I managed to connect to the Internet using wvdial, however I am getting hardly exciting download speeds around 50 kB/s. I was really hoping to get somewhere around 150 - 300 kB/s. Hence my question: how can I "debug" the connection in Linux, i.e. What is the signal strength and if it managed to connect using 3G or only GSM?

I am using Huawei e272 usb modem (branded Vodafone, I am connecting to Virgin though). My wvdial.conf file:

```
[Dialer Defaults]                                                                    
Phone = *99***1#                                  
Username = user                             
Password = " "                                                 
Stupid Mode = 1                                   
Dial Command = ATDT                 

[Dialer hsdpa]                                
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0                           
Baud = 460800                                        
Init2 = ATZ                                        
Init3 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0                    
ISDN = 0                                                      
Modem Type = Analog Modem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only see the signal strength by adding this line into wvdial.conf :

Init4 = AT+CSQ

The Values are Min-Max = 0 - 30. For the type of connection i can only see it by the lights on the device. And i have the same problem about how to manage gsm or 3g only.

Comment: Where can I read the signal strength from?